# Attach LocalDB to microsoft sql server management studio corrupts database

Tags: c#, sql-server

After [complicated migration to LocalDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259563/server-database-to-localdb-migration-error?noredirect=1#comment81480178_47259563) I got strange issue. Currently console application reads data from local DB. But I decided to attach this DB in `Managment Studio`. Got strange error after which none - application and `Studio` cant connect to DB and only SQL server restart helps. Error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The database 'LearnCSharp' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)
```

Database was created wit the same `Management Studio` and version is not issue.

[image]

What does it means and how to have both connections application and `Management Studio` for `LocalDB`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no corruption here - so let's not over-exaggerate the situation. Next time just web search "sql server version 655" to understand version numbers. You are attempting to use a database that was created in a newer version of sql server (2012) in an older (and obsolete) version - 2008. So your claim to the contrary is mistaken unfortunately

**Do not** confuse the version of SSMS with the version of the database instance you are using. If you are not sure, open a query window in SSMS and run the statement "select @@version" to see the instance version. "About SSMS" only shows you the version information of the SSMS application.